# Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE on aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a Spring Boot (Web Starter) work on AWS Lambda and have a class not found exception.  I checked MANIFEST.MF and there's a spring classpath set but not a normal classpath.  I think what's happening is that in the lambda configuration you set a Handler class, but it can't find it because that class is actually in BOOT-INF.

One thing I think might be a problem is that I have two maven plugins configured:

- spring-boot-maven-plugin
- maven-shade-plugin

and I'm wondering if they are conflicting with each other.  My shading plugin configuration excludes tomcat and undertow, but the shaded jar is the same size as the non-shaded one which isn't right.

One stackoverflow suggested configuring org.springframework.boot to use the MODULE layout, but MODULE has been removed.

Is there a known workaround for this?  I could convert this to a non "starter" spring project but that's a lot of effort and I have this sinking feeling it won't solve anything.  In the absence of better ideas perhaps that's what I will have to do.

Comment: I'm curious to why you want to put all of that in a lambda. what part of boot do you want to use in aws?

Comment: It doesn't need to be boot - I can convert it to just a regular spring web project.  My initial motivation was that I had an EXISTING spring boot project.